# Can I use myself as collateral?

Tags: loans, collateral

I want a big loan and decided I have nothing of tangible worth to support repayment, so I was wondering if I could put myself up (literally) as collateral. I suppose this could be understood as me being a repayment to another person, whichever means necessary. I like this because there's no way to certify a value of a human being besides that of which is financially tallied or of liquid assets.

Could I use myself as a human being as collateral for a million dollar loan? Thanks.

Comment: In most parts of the world, indentured servants / human trafficking / slavery is illegal today.

Comment: Loan sharking, where the collateral might be your knee caps or yourself frozen in carbonite, is also generally illegal.

Comment: If there's no way to certify your value, how would you expect the lender to assess your value to decide whether to make the loan?

Comment: You can still take out life insurance then get a terminal diagnosis:   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viatical_settlement  There was a brief flurry of loaning against life insurance policies upon an HIV/AIDS diagnosis.  But investors got burned by better treatments.

Comment: will the item you purchase with the loan have value? If it does, the item you purchase is the collateral.

Comment: In a metaphorical sense, working for someone for a long time is somewhat like collateralizing yourself.

Comment: This would only work in countries where slavery is legal.  Seeing as as slavery is frowned upon in every civilized society around the world, I'm downvoting this and flagging it for removal.

Comment: It could also just be a misunderstanding about how loans/collateral work - I think it has reasonable answers debunking the premise.

Comment: In what sense do you mean yourself as collateral? Your organs and body parts? Enslavement? Im not sure what sense you mean to use humans as collateral so cant really know how one could answer.

Answer (score 10):

Typically lenders don't support human collateral because of the lack of legal remedies for repayment, currently.

Humans have been collateralized in the past and so there adequate references into how that can work if you were able to create an OTC financial agreement with a counterparty.

In more favorable regulatory climates, males encounter difficulty generating income from their bodies to support granting you a loan of the amounts you specified, but there are lucrative opportunities for females. Indeed, some of the biggest establishments that exist to support such services were previously debtor's prisons (that offered the same services).

As others have pointed out, selling body parts can be lucrative, and offering services such as surrogacy can also have a high premium on them, but they all have various limitations such as only having one of a body part, or a womb can only be occupied for a client one at a time, making these inadequate for securing a 1 million dollar loan with interest.

Alternatively, unsecured credit can result in substantial amounts of capital at higher interest rates, so this should be considered an option, and you will have to build up your access to capital in a way that makes institutions comfortable giving you credit lines without pledging assets.

Comment: The whole wink-wink nudge-nudge you-could-be-a-prostitute thing detracts from a reasonable answer. Men can and do "go on the hustle" and sure, they don't like doing that. What makes you think that women do? Drop the paragraph and you have a serious and useful answer.

Comment: @KateGregory the statement wasn't about what people want to do, it was about the market value of what they can do.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned there **is** a lucrative market for men to "generate income from their bodies" (or at least as lucrative as the equivalent market for women), you just don't seem to be aware of it. Anyway the whole thing is a ridiculous red herring which seems to have been included for humour value and detracts, as I said, from a reasonable answer.

Comment: There are also things other than prostitution that could be referred to, such as being a surrogate for a couple that cannot get pregnant, or a paid sperm/egg donor, or the sale of plasma. In other countries, you may also have the ability to sell kidneys, a portion of your liver, or other body parts, & at least 1 person has sold their body as a location for tattoo advertisements. "Sell yourself" has multiple meanings...

Comment: @Vogie OP wants a 1 million dollar unsecured loan. I went for the most lucrative market formed by a constriction of supply and infinite demand, and I phrased it in the most cordial uncontentious way possible. I had improperly undervalued the price of surrogates, livers and kidneys, but I see the limitations of those markets especially in the ability to collateralize 1 million with interest.

Answer (score 0):

How would you pay using the collateral if the loan came up due? :)  Yet many loans do rely on your "human collateral," it's calculated as your credit score, which they view as "your personal ability to pay back over time" so work slowly on raising that.  Good luck! :)

Comment: downvoters leave comments please, cheers!